# How to use pandas to open and read text file, and find a specific piece of data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to open a text file using pandas in Jupyter Notebook.  Then iterating through the file, and search and find specific piece of data.  Then save the rows of the searched data to a new file.

What I need to do:

1. Open text file using pandas in Jupyter Notebook
2. Iterate through the file, searching for "Richmond Group" data
3. Save Only the new search information to a new file

I can not get passed the error to finish the code.
I am struggling to open the file and finding the search data.  Please help me.

### MY CODE:

```
import pandas as df

df=pd.read_csv('F:/Wells FargoZinitra.txt', 'r')

print(df)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: `import pandas as pd` not as `df`

Comment: change `import pandas as df` to `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Please have a look to Asking part in Help Center, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The task is not clear by saying _finding a specific piece of data_ and _searching for "Richmond Group" data_. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

To read data from CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')
#put 'r' before the path string to address any special characters in the path.
df = pd.read_csv(r'F:/Wells FargoZinitra.csv')  
print (df) #df is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

To save data in CSV file:

```
#df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the CSV file\File name.csv',sep =",",index = True)
df.to_csv(r'F:/Wells FargoZinitra2.csv')
```

To select rows from a dataframe:

You can check the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) and select which condition is suitable to your case.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer, let try my problem with you.  I have a file with about 1,000 rows and 4 columns.  Columns are "Product", "Cost", "Quantity", "Purchase" & "Customer"

Comment: I am looking to find a product bought by a customer and find the total amount bought by that costumer.  Then create a file for that costumer for auditing.

Comment: To get help, I advise you to divide your problem to sub objectives, for example :
 How to read CSV file in pandas, How to find a product bought by a customer (_How to get column's value/s based on row value_). How to find the total amount bought of a customer.(_How to sum values in a column based on row value_), How to save CSV file in pandas. Then try to solve it one by one, and post the programming problems which faced you.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Pandas are just in memory tables and it needs to be in a specific format.

2.) If it's a flat file( like csv), try Saving it with that extension

Below is how you do it

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('F:/Wells FargoZinitra.csv')

print(df)
```

Either change it to csv format or use a delimiter in it.

This link might prove to be helpful for you : https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics

If you're new to python, I'd suggest you start from the basics.